# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to parse Json Array from URL using this code.

```
public class Main {
static class Item {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("timelimitstart")
    public String timelimitstart;

    @SerializedName("timelimitend")
    public String timelimitend;

    @SerializedName("esttime")
    public String esttime;

    @SerializedName("location")
    public String location;

    @SerializedName("description")
    public String description;
}

private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int read;
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
            buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String fromURL = readUrl("http://ec2-54-69-156-10.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/getactivities.php");
    String nonURL = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Mine raamatukokku\",\"timelimitstart\":\"\",\"timelimitend\":\"\",\"esttime\":\"00:00:00\",\"location\":\"\",\"description\":\"Mine Ćµpi!\"},{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Mine raamatukokku\",\"timelimitstart\":\"\",\"timelimitend\":\"\",\"esttime\":\"00:00:00\",\"location\":\"\",\"description\":\"Mine Ćµpi!\"}]";

    Item[] data = gson.fromJson(nonURL, Item[].class);

}

}
```

It works with the nonURL input and parses just fine, but with fromURL input it says "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING".

I'm thinking that fromURL it has \" in front of [ and that's why it has problems, but I'm out of ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: If I request that URL, I get a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the file content. You probably want to skip that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response you get from the url has `<meta charset="UTF-8">` at its first line (you can see it with directly browsing the url from a browser and view its source):

To make it a valid json you can remove that line:

```
String fromURL = readUrl("http://ec2-54-69-156-10.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/getactivities.php");

fromURL = fromURL.replace("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">", "");
Item[] data = gson.fromJson(fromURL, Item[].class);
```

**Edit:**
Current response of http://ec2-54-69-156-10.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/getactivities.php:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
[{"id":"1","name":"Mine raamatukokku","timelimitstart":"","timelimitend":"","esttime":"00:00:00","location":"","description":"Mine õpi!"},{"id":"2","name":"Mine jooksma","timelimitstart":"","timelimitend":"","esttime":"00:00:00","location":"","description":"Sport on hea"},{"id":"3","name":"Tee uinak","timelimitstart":"","timelimitend":"","esttime":"00:00:00","location":"","description":"1 tund"}]
```